# How to force an update of a css selector inside context?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's say we have some CSS code:

```
.context-1 .test {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

.context-2 .test {
  background-color: #00ff00;
}

.context-3 .test {
  background-color: #0000ff;
}

<div class="context-1">
    <div class="test">
        Hello, World!
    </div>
</div>
```

Works great. But if I'm trying to switch `.context-1` to `.context-2` - my `div.test` doesn't update it's `background-color`.

Why does the background color not update?

I added a complete source code of such case, here it is:

```js
<script>

var xs = [-Infinity, 768];
var sm = [768, 992];
var md = [992, 1200];
var lg = [1200, Infinity];

var width;

$(window).resize(function() {
 width = $(this).width(); 
 mediaQuery(xs, sm, md, lg);
});

function mediaQuery(xs, sm, md, lg)
{
    if (width >= xs[0] && width < xs[1]) {
        console.log("xs");
        hide_xs();
    }

    if (width >= sm[0] && width < sm[1]) {
        console.log("sm");
        hide_sm();
    }

    if (width >= md[0] && width < md[1]) {
        console.log("md");
        hide_md();
    }

    if (width >= lg[0] && width < lg[1]) {
        console.log("lg");
        hide_lg();
    }
}

function hide_sm() {
    $('#row').removeClass().addClass('xs');
}

function hide_sm() {
    $('#row').removeClass().addClass('sm');
}

function hide_sm() {
    $('#row').removeClass().addClass('md');
}
function hide_lg() {
    $('#row').removeClass().addClass('lg');
}
</script>
```

```css
<style>
.xs .test {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

.sm .test {
  background-color: #00ff00;
}

.md .test {
  background-color: #0000ff;
}

.lg .test {
  background-color: #ff00ff;
}
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="row" class="xs">
 <div class="test">
  Hello, World!
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not valid CSS. Are you using a precompiler or anything?

Comment: Please create a fiddle. You used javascript tag, why? If you have there any JS code, add it too.

Comment: forgotten, yes - sass

Comment: How do you change the css of your div test? Also I think that your css is invalid a correct way to defined it could be:
`.context-3 div.text {
  //Etc
}`

Comment: @vfabre: it's sass, syntax is okay.

Comment: There's not enough code here to reproduce anything.

Comment: @vfabre div.test - is very stright(but ofcourse valid), because I don't know the depth of my .test

Comment: @cimmanon ok, I will post a js script in a few seconds.

Comment: @DzmitryK Can you check my code? Coz I assume you might need something like this!

Comment: Dzmitry, you sass is correct, sorry. I  thought that was vanilla css. @Panther already correct me.

Comment: The sass tag was removed on purpose, do not add it back in unless you're having a Sass->CSS compilation issue.  Also, this is what Media Queries are for.

Comment: I created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ckwqqzb/) and your code works.  i'm missing something? I only change how the script is loggin information.

Comment: @vfabre hey, bro.Leave an answer- I will choose it as a right one. I and it is really right, because older browsers doesn't support context selectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ckwqqzb/) and your code works. The only difference is how the information is logged.

```
function consolelog(message){
    var element = $("#log");
    element.append(message);
}
```

Comment: More details on this question: context selectors (.style-1 .style-2 .style-3) not working in some older browsers, so there was a reason of my question above.